# Metamask Connect Button Not working when adding "Deposit" function

Tags: solidity, metamask, javascript, ethers.js, web3-providers

I'm following a tutorial for a basic app that utilizes Metamask, this is my code in index.js:

```js
import { ethers } from "./ethers-5.6.esm.min.js"
import { abi, contractAddress } from "./constants.js"

const connectButton = document.getElementById("connectButton")
const depositButton = document.getElementById("depositButton")
connectButton.onclick = connect
depositButton.onclick = deposit

console.log(ethers)

async function connect() {
    if (typeof window.ethereum !== "undefined") {
        await ethereum.request({ method: "eth_requestAccounts" })
        connectButton.innerHTML = "Connected"
    } else {
        connectButton.innerHTML = "Mehhh"
    }
}

async function deposit(ethAmount) {
    const ethAmount = "0.01"
    console.log(`Funding with ${ethAmount}`)
    if (typeof window.ethereum !== "undefined") {
        const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum)
        const signer = provider.getSigner()
        const contract = new ethers.contract(contractAddress, abi, provider)
        const transactionResponse = await contract.deposit({
            value: ethers.utils.parseEther(ethAmount),
        })
    }
}
```

This is my code in index.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Kahoot app</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        Helwhats good lO!!
        <script src="./index.js" type="module"></script>
        <button id="connectButton">Connect</button>
        <button id="depositButton">Deposit</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is my constants.js file where the CA & ABI are:

```js
export const contractAddress = "0x327de596178F2A8334f2aBa2BB81A5613dc75499"
export const abi = [
    {
        inputs: [{ internalType: "string", name: "_gameName", type: "string" }],
        stateMutability: "nonpayable",
        type: "constructor",
    },
    {
        inputs: [
            { internalType: "uint256", name: "_qid", type: "uint256" },
            { internalType: "string", name: "_question", type: "string" },
            {
                internalType: "string",
                name: "_answerOne",
                type: "string",
            },
            {
                internalType: "string",
                name: "_answerTwo",
                type: "string",
            },
            {
                internalType: "string",
                name: "_answerThree",
                type: "string",
            },
            {
                internalType: "string",
                name: "_answerFour",
                type: "string",
            },
            {
                internalType: "uint256",
                name: "_correctAnswer",
                type: "uint256",
            },
        ],
        name: "addQuestion",
        outputs: [],
        stateMutability: "nonpayable",
        type: "function",
    },
    {
        inputs: [
            { internalType: "uint256", name: "_id", type: "uint256" },
            {
                internalType: "address",
                name: "_studentAddress",
                type: "address",
            },
            {
                internalType: "string",
                name: "_studentName",
                type: "string",
            },
        ],
        name: "addStudent",
        outputs: [],
        stateMutability: "nonpayable",
        type: "function",
    },
    {
        inputs: [
            { internalType: "uint256", name: "_id", type: "uint256" },
            {
                internalType: "uint256",
                name: "_studentAnswer",
                type: "uint256",
            },
        ],
        name: "answerQuestion",
        outputs: [{ internalType: "bool", name: "", type: "bool" }],
        stateMutability: "nonpayable",
        type: "function",
    },
    {
        inputs: [{ internalType: "uint256", name: "", type: "uint256" }],
        name: "correctAnswerMapping",
        outputs: [{ internalType: "uint256", name: "", type: "uint256" }],
        stateMutability: "view",
        type: "function",
    },
    {
        inputs: [],
        name: "deposit",
        outputs: [],
        stateMutability: "payable",
        type: "function",
    },
    {
        inputs: [
            { internalType: "address", name: "", type: "address" },
            { internalType: "uint256", name: "", type: "uint256" },
        ],
        name: "didStudentRespond",
        outputs: [{ internalType: "uint256", name: "", type: "uint256" }],
        stateMutability: "view",
        type: "function",
    },
    {
        inputs: [{ internalType: "uint256", name: "_id", type: "uint256" }],
        name: "fetchAnswers",
        outputs: [{ internalType: "string[]", name: "", type: "string[]" }],
        stateMutability: "view",
        type: "function",
    },
    {
        inputs: [{ internalType: "uint256", name: "_qid", type: "uint256" }],
        name: "fetchQuestion",
        outputs: [{ internalType: "string", name: "", type: "string" }],
        stateMutability: "view",
        type: "function",
    },
    {
        inputs: [{ internalType: "uint256", name: "", type: "uint256" }],
        name: "idQuestions",
        outputs: [{ internalType: "string", name: "", type: "string" }],
        stateMutability: "view",
        type: "function",
    },
    {
        inputs: [
            {
                internalType: "address",
                name: "_studentAddress",
                type: "address",
            },
        ],
        name: "isThisAddressStudent",
        outputs: [{ internalType: "bool", name: "", type: "bool" }],
        stateMutability: "view",
        type: "function",
    },
    {
        inputs: [],
        name: "owner",
        outputs: [
            { internalType: "address payable", name: "", type: "address" },
        ],
        stateMutability: "view",
        type: "function",
    },
    {
        inputs: [
            { internalType: "uint256", name: "", type: "uint256" },
            { internalType: "uint256", name: "", type: "uint256" },
        ],
        name: "questionAnswers",
        outputs: [{ internalType: "string", name: "", type: "string" }],
        stateMutability: "view",
        type: "function",
    },
    {
        inputs: [
            { internalType: "uint256", name: "", type: "uint256" },
            { internalType: "string", name: "", type: "string" },
        ],
        name: "questions",
        outputs: [
            {
                internalType: "uint256",
                name: "correctAnswer",
                type: "uint256",
            },
        ],
        stateMutability: "view",
        type: "function",
    },
    {
        inputs: [
            { internalType: "address", name: "_address", type: "address" },
        ],
        name: "questionsAnsweredByStudent",
        outputs: [{ internalType: "uint256[]", name: "", type: "uint256[]" }],
        stateMutability: "view",
        type: "function",
    },
    {
        inputs: [
            { internalType: "uint256", name: "", type: "uint256" },
            { internalType: "string", name: "", type: "string" },
        ],
        name: "students",
        outputs: [{ internalType: "address", name: "", type: "address" }],
        stateMutability: "view",
        type: "function",
    },
    {
        inputs: [{ internalType: "uint256", name: "", type: "uint256" }],
        name: "studentsAddresses",
        outputs: [{ internalType: "address", name: "", type: "address" }],
        stateMutability: "view",
        type: "function",
    },
    {
        inputs: [{ internalType: "address", name: "", type: "address" }],
        name: "studentsIds",
        outputs: [{ internalType: "uint256", name: "", type: "uint256" }],
        stateMutability: "view",
        type: "function",
    },
]
```

Contract is deployed on Goerli, for some reason the "deposit" function in index.js makes it so that i can not connect my Metamask to the app. When i comment the "deposit" function out, the Metamask connection works perfectly fine, when i comment it back in it does not work again - Not sure what the override is... Would appreciate any help!

Comment: Are you testing it in Remix IDE?